# Maximize trace of matrix equation given two constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, trace

Let $\mathbf{Q}$ be a rotation matrix and $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be two real-valued matrices of the same size. I want to maximize the function
$$
f(\mathbf{Q})=tr\;\mathbf{QA} \qquad \text{s.t.} \; \mathbf{Q}'\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{I} \quad \text{and} \quad  tr\; \mathbf{QB} \geq 0
$$

If only the orthogonality constraint is imposed, the solution is 
$$
\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{VU}' 
$$

(see e.g. [Cliff, 1966](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02289455#page-1)) with $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ from the singular value decomposition of $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U \Lambda V}'$.

***Question*: How can I find a solution that also includes the second constraint, i.e. $tr\; \mathbf{QB} \geq 0$, given that it exists?**

Footnote: I am not a mathematician, so please be verbose in your answer, so I have a chance to follow :)

**Literature**

Cliff, N. (1966). Orthogonal rotation to congruence. Psychometrika, 31(1), 33–42. http://doi.org/10.1007/BF02289455

Answer (score 2):

The SVD of $A$ is $A=U\Lambda V^T$. If $\det(A)\not=0$, then the so-called solution $Q_0=VU^T$ is s.t. $\det(Q_0)=signum(\det(A))=\pm 1$ ; then I assume that $Q\in O(n)$.

Let $C=U^TBV,R=V^TQU\in O(n)$. If $tr(Q_0B)=tr(C)\geq 0$, then the solution is $Q_0$.

Assume that $tr(C)<0$. One has $tr(QA)=tr(R\Lambda)$ ; the sup is reached when $tr(QB)=tr(VRU^TB)=tr(RC)=0$ (not exactly; cf. EDIT 1. below).

Then it remains to find $\sup_{R\in O(n)}tr(R\Lambda)$ under the condition that $tr(RC)=0$.

EDIT 1. Assume that the sup of $g(R)=tr(R\Lambda)$ is reached in $R=R_1$ with $tr(R_1C)>0$. Then $g(R_1)$ is a free local sup of $g$.

Case 1. $R_1\in O^+(n)$. Since $O^+(n)$ is a connected set, $g(R_1)=g(I)=tr(\Lambda)$. If $\Lambda=diag(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_k,0,\cdots,0)$ where $\lambda_i>0$, then  $R_1=diag(I_k,S)$ where $S\in O^+(n-k)$.

Case 2. $R_1\in O^-(n)$. Then $g(R_1)=g(J)$ where $J=diag(u_1,\cdots,u_n)$ with $u_i=\pm 1$.

Unfortunately, Case 2 may occur. Take, for instance, $\Lambda=diag(1,1,0,0,0),C=diag(-3,-3,-2,-2,-3)$. Then the sup is reached in a sole point $R_1=diag(1,1,-1,-1,-1)$ with $tr(R_1C)=1$.

EDIT 2. Answer to Mark. I agree with the case $tr(C)\geq 0$ and your Point A.

About your point B where necessarily $tr(R_1C)>0$.

Case 1: $R_1\in O^+(n)$. Then necessarily $R_1=diag(I_k,S)$ and you seek $S$ s.t. $tr(R_1C)>0$. If $S$ exists, then  $\max(g)=tr(\Lambda)$, else $R_1$ does not exist.

Case 2: $R_1\in O^-(n)$. Then necessarily $(\star)$ $g(R_1)=max_k(g(J_k))$ where $J_k$ is the diagonal matrix s.t. $(J_k)_{i,i}=1$ if $i\not= k$ and  $(J_k)_{k,k}=-1$. You seek $R_1$ satisfying $(\star)$ and s.t. $tr(R_1C)>0$...

Finally, you choose "the" best candidate. Note that Point A is not easy to solve.

EDIT 3. Mark, I do not want to write details; in fact, I use the following results (that are not obvious to prove):

1. Let $O\in O^+(n)$. There is a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow O^+(n)$ s.t. $f(0)=O,f(1)=I$ and s.t., for every $i$,  the function $f_{i,i}$ is non-decreasing.

After discussion with a colleague, a correct statement is:

2. Let $O\in O^-(n)$. There is a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow O^-(n)$ s.t. $f(0)=O$, $f(1)$ has spectrum $\{1,\cdots,1,-1\}$  and s.t., for every $i$,  the function $f_{i,i}$ is non-decreasing.

NB. During such a deformation, $tr(R\Lambda)$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: I understand you propose the following algorithm to solve the problem (please correct me, if I am wrong). Check whether $tr\; \mathbf{C} \geq 0$. If so, we are done. If not solve the following maximization problems: A) Maximize $tr\; \mathbf{R\Lambda}$ with $\mathbf{R} \in O(n)$ under $tr\; \mathbf{RC} = 0$; B) Maximize $tr\; \mathbf{R\Lambda}$ with $\mathbf{R} = diag(\pm1, \dots, \pm1)$ under $tr\; \mathbf{RC} \geq 0$. Last step: Choose the maximum of the two solutions (A and B). Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for you new edits! I have a question concerning them: Referring to case 2: How do you conclude that it is sufficient to seek the maximizing $R_1$ among the matrices $J_1, \dots, J_n$? Doesn't the example you provided in EDIT 1 ($C = diag(-3, -3, -2, -2, -3)$) show that there are cases where $tr(J_k C) < 0$ for all $k$?

Comment: Case 2. is more difficult. Unfortunately, $R_1$ is not necessarily among the $(J_k)_k$, as my instance above proved. STEP 1. You calculate $\alpha=\max_k g(J_k)$. STEP 2.  You consider all $R_1$ s.t. $g(R_1)=\alpha$ and $tr(R_1C)>0$.

Comment: Thanks! I will look at that later. I stumbled across another thing concerning case 1 however: How do you conclude that the maximum $R_1$ must have the form $diag(I_k, S)$? (You argue that the connectedness of $O^+(n)$ implies that $g(R_1) = g(I)$. How can I see that?). I know, many questions, but thanks for your patience!! :)

Comment: Thanks!! Here I go again concerning result 2 in edit 3 :) Either I do not understand the result correctly or I have a counter-example.

Take for instance $O = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $. Since $ det(O) = -1 $, $O \in O^-(2)$. 

We have two choices for $J_k$: $J_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $J_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.
In any case $f_{11}(0) = 0$ and $f_{22}(0) = 0$.
If we choose $J_1$, then we have $f_{11}(1) = -1$. If we choose $J_2$, then we have $f_{22}(0) = -1$. Thus, either $f_{11}$ or $f_{22}$ is not non-decreasing.

Comment: Mark, of course, my result 2. is false. I thought that my proof for 1. works similarly for 2. !! That proves that the case $R_1\in O^-(n)$ is difficult to solve.

Comment: Mark, I edit a correct statement for result 2 in edit 3.