# Maximizing the trace of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, trace, svd

Let's say I have the following maximization problem:

$max_U{tr(AU)}$

where $A\in\mathbb{C}$ and $UU^\dagger=1$

I know that for $A\in\mathbb{R}$ and $UU^T=1$ the solution is:

$U=XZ^T$ where $X$ and $Z$ come from the SVD of $A$, i.e. $A=XYZ^T$

Does this also hold for the complex case? Namely:

$U=XZ^\dagger$ with $A=XYZ^\dagger$

If so, do you have a reference to a proof?

Comment: First of all, you should explain your notation; $\dagger$ meaning complex conjugate is standard in physics but not math. Second, it should be $U=ZX^T$. Third, yes: the same will be true in the complex case. If you can provide a summary or reference for your proof in the real case, perhaps we can find an easy way to extend that same proof.

Comment: In $\dagger$ I mean complex conjugation and transpose.
Why do you say $U=ZX^T$, shouldn't $X$ be also conjugated? Since $XX^\dagger=1$. 
Also I wish to clarify what I mean by maximizing the trace of a complex matrix. So let's say I wish to maximize the real part.

So there are two previous questions on this forum about the real case:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754301/maximizing-the-trace
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208080/maximize-trace-of-matrix-equation-given-two-constraints

Comment: Yes, $X$ should be conjugated in the complex case. I meant that you have $X$ and $Z$ reversed.

Comment: Yes, of course..

Comment: In any case, the proof you provided works in the same way. Over the complex matrices, $$\langle A,B\rangle = tr(AB^\dagger)$$ is a Hermitian (sesquilinear) inner product.

Comment: I am looking here for pointer to literature, because I guessed the answer myself, I want proof. Anyone? BTW, @EyalLeviatan you have the order wrong! $tr(^ \cdot ^)\neq TrY$ Instead $tr(^ \cdot  X^T) = TrY$