# Maximization problem involving trace function

Tags: matrices, optimization, trace

We have the following maximization problem

$\max_X \text{Real}(\text{Tr} (AX)),~~~\text{s.t.}~\text{Tr}(X) \le P, ~~X \geq 0$

And $A$ and $X$ are complex square matrices of the same size. Is the solution to the above problem $X=P\dfrac{A^H}{||A||_F}$?

Comment: Who is $A^{H}$?

Comment: Conjugate transpose of A!

Comment: What do you mean by maximising the trace of $AX$ when the trace is not necessarily a real number?

Comment: I have modified the question. Can u answer it please?

Comment: you are unable to correctly write a question; what do you mean by $X\geq 0$ ? Perhaps $X$ is hermitian $\geq 0$ ? On the other hand, I assume that $A\not= 0$. What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximize trace of matrix equation given two constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208080/maximize-trace-of-matrix-equation-given-two-constraints)